# If $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ then $M_1^2 \le 2M_0 M_2$, where $M_k = \text {sup}_x |(d/dx)^k f(x)|$ for $k=0,1,2.$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I wanna prove this problem. I tried it with Mean Value Theorem but cannot proceed to any plausible result. So could I have some hints?

Comment: This is a case of the so-called Laundau-Kolmogorov inequalitites: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mean value theorem generally doesn't work on problems involving $C^2$ functions, but the generalization does. From Taylor's theorem, for any $x,h \in \mathbb R$,
\begin{align*}
f(x + h) &= f(x) + h\cdot f'(x) + h^2 \cdot \frac{f''(\zeta_1)}{2} \\
f(x - h) &= f(x) - h\cdot f'(x) + h^2 \cdot \frac{f''(\zeta_2)}{2}
\end{align*}
for some $\zeta_1$ between $x$ and $x + h$ and $\zeta_2$ between $x$ and $x - h$. Subtracting,
\begin{align*}
f(x+h) - f(x-h) &= 2h \cdot f'(x) - \frac{h^2}{2} \left(\,f''(\zeta_1) - f''(\zeta_2) \right)
\end{align*}
Solving for $f'(x)$ and bounding,
\begin{align*}
|f'(x)| &= \left| \frac{1}{2h} \left( f(x+h) - f(x-h) \right) + \frac{h}{4}\left(\,f''(\zeta_1) - f''(\zeta_2) \right) \right| \\
&\leq \frac{M_0}{h} + \frac{hM_2}{2}
\end{align*}
Taking the sup over all $x$ gives
$$M_1 \leq \frac{M_0}{h} + \frac{hM_2}{2}.$$
Rearranging and simplifying, 
$$M_2h^2 - 2M_1h + 2M_0 \geq 0.$$
I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: If I were pedantic I'd criticize you for writing ($x,x+2h)$ when $ h$ might be negative.But restricting $ h$ to positive values works verbatim. And your last line should not be strict inequality.I give you an upvote as is.

Comment: ~Typos~ $\qquad{}$

Comment: @Nitin From your approach, I obtained $M_1^2 \le 4M_0 M_2$ not $M_1^2 \le 2M_0 M_2$. Do I think something wrong?

Comment: You're correct -- I fixed it.